# How to get Image Path just captured from camera

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

below is my code but is not give me image path in onActivity result

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                Log.w("jay", "Camera Image Path :" + selectedImagePath);

                Toast.makeText(MiscansOther_pannel.this, selectedImagePath,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This works for me...

**Code:**

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
selectedImagePath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
```

Method: `getRealPathFromURI()`

```
//----------------------------------------
    /**
     * This method is used to get real path of file from from uri
     * 
     * @param contentUri
     * @return String
     */
    //----------------------------------------
    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri)
    {
        try
        {
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return contentUri.getPath();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

As I noticed in some device after captured image the data in `onActivityResult()` is **null**,

So the alternate way, Pass the specific image filename as a argument to your Intent for capture image as `putExtra` parameter.

Then also insert this image Uri in Media Store, Now use this Uri for your further use,

You can check whether image is captured or not by `File.exist()`,

Code looks like,

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "Image File name");
Uri mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
Intent intentPicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intentPicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
startActivityForResult(intentPicture,ACTION_TAKE_PICTURE);
```

Now, you can use the same method for get file path from Uri,

in this case it will be in `onActivityResult()`,

```
selectedImagePath = getRealPathFromURI(mCapturedImageURI); // don't use data.getData() as it return null in some device instead  use mCapturedImageUR uri variable statically in your code,
```

Comment: except if you are using a Samsung.

Comment: @OvidiuLatcu - I didn't tested it on Samsung. What is the problem in Samsung device using this code?

Comment: Hm, i know its been over a year, but when i use the code you posted the image i take gets saved 2x, once in default DCIM/100MEDIA folder where all camera shots go and once in DCIM/CAMERA folder...and most importantly the image doesnt get the name i specified as "Image File Name"...it just gets a random number.

Comment: I would like to say that for me this was giving RunTimeException. I solved using: ``intentPicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getRealPathFromURI(mCapturedImageURI));`` - like, passing the String, not URI.

Comment: data.getData(); onActivityResult() will give thumbnail only

Comment: @user370305 if is it possible to give you 1000 upvots, sure i will give you,I was looking for this type of solutions. Thank you very much, using your code now i am able to send my image taken by camera to remote server with compress and without loose of image quality.