# Android intent.getData() Nullpointer exceptipon

Tags: java, android

I have an android app that start the smartphone camera

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST );
```

To display the taken picture I use this piece of code,

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    setImage=true;
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if(data!=null)
        {
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagePreview);
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
             Bitmap mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
             image.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
        }
   }
}
```

This works pretty fine but if i want to get the path of the taken picture, i have to use `(intent)data.getData()` but this returns a `null` value. what should i do to solve this problem?

Comment: have u tried it as  `Bitmap mImageBitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Image Path just captured from camera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591825/how-to-get-image-path-just-captured-from-camera)

Comment: but i need the path not the bitmap.....i have already the right bitmap object....

Comment: @Waqas yeah but data.getData() doesnt work....and i need this for your linked solution

Comment: @Dennis : to get real path of image you will need to query `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA` column from `MediaStore` contentProvider

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below:

> ```
>       Bitmap m_photo = (Bitmap) p_data.getExtras().get("data");
>     if (m_photo != null)
>     {
>     ByteArrayOutputStream m_upByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
>     m_photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 40, m_upByteArrayOutputStream);
>     Drawable m_imageFromCamera = new BitmapDrawable(m_photo);
>              image.setBackgroundDrawable(m_photo);
>       }
> ```

**EDITED:**

To get the Path of the image try out below code:

> ```
>      Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
>         String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
>         Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
>                 filePathColumn, null, null, null);
>         cursor.moveToFirst();
>         int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
>         String imagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex); <---- Here is your image path.
>         cursor.close();
> ```

Comment: but i need only the path of the picture

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it helps you.

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            String imageName = picturePath.substring(picturePath.lastIndexOf(
                    "/", picturePath.length()));
```