# setting or getting uri of captured image

Tags: android

I'm creating an image filter app in Android studio. first, the user selects an image from gallery or captures image using camera and it will be displayed in imageview. Then the user clicks edit button and that image is displayed in imageview of next activity where we can add filters... It works fine with low resolution images but when I select any high resolution image or click a high resolution image it is shown in first imageview but when I click edit button either the app crashes or the last image I had selected is displayed. So instead of passing bitmap I thought of passing image uri.I found the solution for image selected from gallery but I want the uri of captured image. I searched for the solution but couldn't find it. If anyone knows how to solve this problem please help me. THANKS

Comment: please share your logcat

Comment: share stacktrace and your code

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the code of what you have tried. A quick google search gave me this answer: [How to get Image Path just captured from camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591825/how-to-get-image-path-just-captured-from-camera) . hope it helps